# unsupported document class detected with Copernicus Latex Package

Tags: packages, warnings, documentclass

I’m trying to compile the template of the Copernicus Latex package (used for Copernicus journals). I downloaded the package from Copernicus website: https://publications.copernicus.org/for_authors/manuscript_preparation.html#templates

I get the warning “Unsupported document class (or package) detected,(caption) usage of the caption package is not recommended” that refers to the file caption.sty

Besides that they layout of the compiled document is 1-column whereas I expect it to be 2-columns (not sure about that, it’s my first submission to a Copernicus journal).

So I have 3 questions:

1. Is it normal that the layout is 1-column and not 2-columns?
2. What causes the “Unsupported document class” warning?
3. Is this warning important or can I go on with the writing without worrying about it?

Here is a code snippet of the beginning of the template that compiles:

```
%% Copernicus Publications Manuscript Preparation Template for LaTeX Submissions
%% ---------------------------------
%% This template should be used for copernicus.cls
%% The class file and some style files are bundled in the Copernicus Latex Package, which can be downloaded from the different journal webpages.
%% For further assistance please contact Copernicus Publications at: production@copernicus.org
%% https://publications.copernicus.org/for_authors/manuscript_preparation.html


%% Please use the following documentclass and journal abbreviations for preprints and final revised papers.

%% 2-column papers and preprints
\documentclass[wcd, manuscript]{copernicus}

%% Journal abbreviations (please use the same for preprints and final revised papers)

% Weather and Climate Dynamics (wcd)



%% \usepackage commands included in the copernicus.cls:
%\usepackage[german, english]{babel}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{cancel}
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{supertabular}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{rotating}


\begin{document}

\title{TEXT}


% \Author[affil]{given_name}{surname}

\Author[]{}{}
\Author[]{}{}
\Author[]{}{}

\affil[]{ADDRESS}
\affil[]{ADDRESS}


\correspondence{NAME (EMAIL)}

\runningtitle{TEXT}

\runningauthor{TEXT}


\firstpage{1}

\maketitle



\begin{abstract}
TEXT
\end{abstract}


\copyrightstatement{TEXT} %% This section is optional and can be used for copyright transfers.


\introduction  %% \introduction[modified heading if necessary]
TEXT


\section{HEADING}
TEXT

\conclusions  %% \conclusions[modified heading if necessary]
TEXT

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`caption` package patches the `\caption` command to add additional features.
It does this assuming the original behaviour is the same or close to `\caption` in `article` class.

Normally if you use a publisher class with radically different caption layout and try to load `caption` package in the document, you get this warning, warning that it may not work correctly.

Here though the authors of the class are loading `caption` *within the class itself* and choosing to ignore (rather than silence) the warning. That's a bit unfortunate but it is by design, so as a user you can assume that the behaviour is as intended, and the warning is spurious.